# Custom heading text style using \newcommand

Tags: macros, sectioning

I'm trying to create a custom heading style that is centered, bold, large and has some 0.2cm vertical space before and after. I'd like to retain the normal section headings. Below is my attempt using `\newcommand`.

My questions:

- How can I add vertical space after the heading style?
- How can I avoid that the subsequent text gets formatted as well?

Many thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\progtitel{\vspace{0.2cm}\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
Normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text

\progtitel{Custom Title}

Normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why fon't you use `\part*`? You can easily customise its layout with `titlesec`.

Comment: unfortuantely, I'm not very familiar with the method you suggest. How would this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a starting point. You were missing a `\vspace` and a grouping of the command, which now only takes one argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\progtitel[1]{{\vspace{0.2cm}\begin{center}\Large\bfseries #1 \end{center}\vspace{0.2cm}}}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}

Normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text

\progtitel{Custom Title}

Normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: exactly what I needed - many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The tricky bit was making it independent of `\parskip` and having it behave the same with or without blank lines around it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\progtitel}[1]% #1 = title
{\vspace{\dimexpr 0.2cm-\parskip}\hrule height0pt
  \noindent\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries #1}%
  \vspace{\dimexpr 0.2cm-\parskip}\hrule height0pt
  \@afterheading}% no indentation for first paragraph
\makeatletter

%\parskip=\baselineskip

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
Normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text

\progtitel{Custom Title}

Normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This solution using a `trivlist` instead of `\hrule`, but the end result is more complicated, not less.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\progtitel}[1]% #1 = title
{\bgroup
  \topsep=\dimexpr 0.2cm-\parskip\relax
  \partopsep=0pt
  \trivlist
    \item\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries #1}%
  \endtrivlist
\egroup\@afterheading}% no indentation for first paragraph
\makeatletter

%\parskip=\baselineskip

\begin{document}


\section{My section}
Normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text

\progtitel{Custom Title}

Normal text normal text normal text normal text normal text

\end{document}
```